Azure Dev Ops stoped pipeline can't connect to Azure resources anymore
I have a pipeline in Azure devOps that deploys the Azure data factory and related resources (keyvaults copy, global variable sets, etc..) to various environments (prod, dev, uat)
It worked for over a year.  I used to have the DevOps project as managed identity allowed to access ADF.  That secret has expired, and I went ahead to create a new on.
I stripped down the deployment script to a simple output
Param(
[Parameter(Mandatory)]
[string]$subscriptionId,            #Azure Subscription ID

  )

  Write-Host Subscription $subscriptionId

I get the errors like this when I run deployment.

Can anyone help with the steps involved?  I understand there were some recent changes in how Azure manages this, but am not sure where to start ?

"_ I used to have the DevOps project as managed identity..._" - does this managed identity still exist? Script is failing with error Could not find tenant id...

Yes, the managed identity still exist.  My tenant id and subscription id did not change.  The only change from my side was that the managed identity of a devops pipeline had a client id/secret expired.  Initially the error was about that and I recreated that.  But now, I can't find how to set it in the Access controll for subscription.

Hi, please copy the full error message and share it in text. The error message in the screenshot is incomplete. It may contain an Original exception with error code, see a sample question here. By the way, can you please share a Minimal, Reproducible code example  to better troubleshooting the issue? For example, the task you are using, the way you use your managed identity in the pipeline.

Where is your managed identity,  Can you show your managed identity location with a snapshot with more details ?
